# Matching data from two different excel spreadsheets

Tags: excel

I have two separate excel spreadsheets, one contains a list of clients with account number as well as their monthly billed revenue. The second spreadsheet I have was pulled from Salesforce.com and contains the account name, account number and Salesforce system ID number. I need to match the account number on the spreadsheet containing revenue to the Salesforce account ID number on the other spreadsheet so that I can upload the revenue for each account into Salesforce. The Salesforce account ID number is what allows me to map the revenue data to the appropriate account in salesforce. Additionally, once I can figure out a way to match these, I can provide the data to accounting so that this number can be appended to the records on their end for future reporting services. I have researching sites and it appears that this can be done. Do these need to be the same spreadsheet with separate sheets or all in one? it appears this can be accomplished with a formula; however this is my first venture into something this complex in excel. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: and you could try the [VLOOKUP Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need the VLOOKUP function.  This allows you to display a value in a cell from a column in another sheet, using the account number as your common field.

[**I made this**](http://2toria.com/2010/04/28/downloads-interactive-excel-tutorial-vlookup/) ages ago to explain how to use VLOOKUPS.  Might be of some use.